# List Comprehension to Recursion [Haskell]

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, list-comprehension

I have the following function, which divides a list of Maybes with an Int input.

```
divideList :: Int -> [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Double]
```

i.e.

```
 divideList 100 [Just 5, Just 4, Nothing]   == [Just 20, Just 25.0, Nothing]
```

As a reminder the Maybe datatype is defined as follows:

```
 data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

My code looks(and works) as followings:

```
divideList m xs = [ div2 x | x <- xs]
    where
        div2 (Just n) | n > 0   = Just (fromIntegral m / fromIntegral n)
        div2 _                  = Nothing
```

Now I'm trying to write the same function again, but this time just with recursion and without list comprehensions. However I can't seem to get it working.

Here's my (wrong) guess:

```
divideList m xs = div2  x 
    where
        div2 (Just x) | x > 0   = Just (fromIntegral m / fromIntegral x)
        div2 _                  = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.

1. First define the division function separately

   ```
   div3 :: Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Double
   div3 i (Just n) | n > 0 = Just (fromIntegral i / fromIntegral n)
   div3 i _                = Nothing
   ```
2. Then, for each item in the list, call the `div3` and concatenate it with the result of the recursive call to `divideList`, like this

   ```
   divideList :: Int -> [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Double]
   divideList _ [] = []
   divideList m (x:xs) = (div3 m x):(divideList m xs)
   ```

Here,

```
divideList _ [] = []
```

is called the *base condition* of your recursion. That decides when your recursion ends.

Comment: I'd like to mention that this is essentially the `map` function specialized for `div3`.

Comment: @bheklilr Since he already knows list comprehension, we can safely assume that he knows about `map` as well, I guess. :)

Answer (score 3):

What I always recommend is this: do **not** write direct recursive solutions like what you're trying to do.  They're not idiomatic, they're harder to read, and they get pretty hard to write once you're doing anything complex.

Instead, figure out how to write your solution with standard library functions like `map`, `filter` and so on.  Then, as an exercise, write your own versions of those library functions.  In this case:

```
divideList m xs = map div2 xs
    where
        div2 (Just n) | n > 0   = Just (fromIntegral m / fromIntegral n)
        div2 _                  = Nothing

-- Apply the function `f` to each element of the list, returning a list of the results,
-- in the order of the corresponding arguments.
map f []     = _   -- Fill me in
map f (x:xs) = _   -- Fill me in
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to write first a function for the division of two integral numbers. It must return a `Maybe Double`, as the calculation isn't always possible.

```
div2 m n = if n <= 0 then Nothing else Just (fromIntegral m / fromIntegral n)
```

Then you just need to apply this function to every element of the list, which can be done with `map`. However, as the number is "hidden" in a `Maybe`, you can use the function `(>>=)` to "unwrap" it (when it isn't a `Nothing`, which stays a `Nothing`, as we want).

```
divideList m xs = map (>>= div2 m) xs
```

Or shorter:

```
divideList m = map (>>= div2 m)
```